# how to solve opacity css in cordova android?

Tags: android, cordova

in my cordova app i set for div opacity

opacity: 0.6 !important;

while it work in android <5.1

and it not work in android >5.1,6 ,...

i set in css

```
     filter: alpha(opacity=50);
     opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .15s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0.6 !important;
    visibility: visible;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

it fixed in emulator version 6
but in real device same issue exist